# How to set imageview in UIActionSheet in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

In my application having sharing option so i want to open that sharing option in Actionsheet. 
how how to achieve this functionality?

```
NSArray * itemsArray = @[@"www.google.com", @"Google", @"5.png"]; // Anything you want to share
NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;

UIActivityViewController * activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsArray applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"))
{
     activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
}
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

i want to assign my own custom image, link and text so how to achieve this

[image]

Comment: please post your effort

Comment: please check my uploaded image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use an `UIActivityViewController` instead? So the system can handle where to share it:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)


UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"];
NSArray * itemsArray = @[image]; // Anything you want to share


    NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;

    UIActivityViewController * activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsArray applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[
                                                     UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                                     UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                                     UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                                     UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList
                                                     // Whatever you want to exclude
                                                     ];

    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")){
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
    }

    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: NSArray * itemsArray = @[url ? url : [NSNull null], title ? title : [NSNull null], image ? image : [NSNull null]];
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")){
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = viewController.view;
    }

    [viewController presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
got an error in this lines

Comment: Replace `url`, `title` and `image` for your objects. Actually, just add to the array what you want to share.

Comment: What error do you get? I modified my solution, just copy and paste the whole code and replace url, title and image by your objects

Comment: use of undeclared identifier viewcontroller

Comment: `viewController` is your view controller, so probably `self` for you, replace `viewController` by `self`. And url, title and image *must be your objects*. If you're sharing an image replace them with your image.

Comment: but how to assign custom image to UIActivityViewController

Comment: I edited the answer, with the steps I told you to do... I can't help more than that... If you need more help then show your code and we'll try to figure out what's wrong...

Comment: i want only this 4 option 1.Mail

2.Contact

3.Whats App

4.Facebook .

Comment: Exclude everything else then, in the 'excludeActivityTypes' array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88864/discussion-between-stela-and-pablo-a).